# How to add animation to an image/container when scrolling?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, scroll

I require some help creating a scroll effect for a client.

Example: If you scroll down the page, notice how the image on the right animates to become full width and it almost has a parallex type animation where the width and image position is changing at slightly different speeds.

https://videinfra.com/work/fci

I have had a go myself using JS and some CSS animations but can't get the desired result. Does anyone know the code or a plugin which may handle this?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're after, but check out AOS (Animate On Scroll): https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/

Answer (score 0):

You could use "Animate on Scroll" libraries, such as WOW.js (https://wowjs.uk/) and AOS (https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/).

These two are excellent when it comes to firing animations when your element becomes visible in the viewport. I've been using WOW for years. Have a look at their documentation, it will get you started.